# Shortcut for selecting the first song result from search in iTunes

Tags: macos, itunes, keyboard, shortcut

Often times I find myself searching for a song in my library and as expected iTunes filters my results. I wanted to know is there a quick way for me to be a to jump right to that first result instead of manually mousing over and clicking it to play. You would think it would be the tab button but that directs me to the left column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the sidebar isn't shown (the current default), in iTunes v 11.3.1, I'm able to:

1. search (hit enter if you get the popdown results instead of the full window update)
2. tab
3. even though the song
   isn't highlighted, I can just hit space and the top song starts
   playing.

If you use the arrow keys instead, you can see that the first song gets selected, and then you can navigate the search results from there.

If the sidebar IS shown, everything is the same, but you'll need to hit tab twice.  As an aside, toggle the sidebar with <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>alt</kbd><kbd>s</kbd>

This is on Mac, on Windows YMMV.

Comment: I'm on a mac too but the first tab click brings me to the left column despite your directions.

Comment: I just updated the answer to reflect how to get there if the sidebar is shown.... basically, hit tab twice.

Comment: Works great. The only caveat (not even sure if there's a workaround for this) is after the second tab you manually have to hit the down arrow key to get to the first result and hit enter to play it. Makes a 4 step process but works nonetheless. If there is a workaround by all means. Thanks for your help.